# Powershell script to auto delete, download and restore SQL database not executing fully

Tags: sql, powershell, winscp

With the help from some online resources I've compiled a PowerShell script that will:

- Delete any file older than 60 minutes in a set folder
- Connect to an SFTP server and download a single .bak file
- Restore the downloaded .bak file to a SQL instance

The code works fine if I break it out and run it individually. However, when I combine them it runs until the restore and just stops.  Below is the code. Any help identifying why I can select the restore script, run it only and it works, but not when this is run as a whole would be helpful.

Update 1: I have created a simplified version of the code that still does not function, but only has the connection using WINSCP, kill process of SSMS and restore.  The kill process is simply a visual queue for me to see it is executing.

**Update 2: I have found that putting the restore script inside the session.open it will run fine. However I don't feel comfortable leaving the session open as the sql does it's restore, that feels...i don't how to put it, but wrong.**

```
$localPath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\MSSQL\Backup\"

# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"

# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "url.com"
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "password"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh stuff"
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }  
    exit 0
catch
{ 
   Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"    
    exit 1
}

        #restore database
        $Program = Get-Process SSMS -erroraction SilentlyContinue
        if ($Program)
        {
        $Program.closeMainWindow()
        Sleep 5
        If (!$Program.hasexited)
        {
        $program | stop-process -force
        }
        }
        remove-variable Program
        $FileNam = Get-ChildItem -path $localpath

        Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "machine\instance" -Database "Test" -BackupFile $FileName -ReplaceDatabase
```

Comment: Why are you killing SSMS like that? It's not necessary when restoring a database.

Comment: How many files are in `$path` when you call `$FileName = Get-ChildItem -path $path`?

Comment: Killing ssms as a precaution in case anyone is in it. The script runs at 7am after the server cuts on, just some overkill.

There is only 1 file in the folder. I'm using get-childitem as the name varies day to day.

Comment: "runs until the restore and just stops". Maybe it's restoring - login to the SQL Server and use `sp_who2` to check activity on the SQL Server

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for the info. Did a check and it didn't show the powershell script running. I also confirmed it didn't restore because the changes made prior to the script running weren't changed back (i changed a bunch of values to NULL to test).

Answer (score 0):

Answer solved/found.  Moving the restore into the "try" section resolved it, even if it's after the connection disposal.  Most likely it's something to do with exit 0.  Another solution is to remove the try/catch and exit codes entirely.